# Issue Logging in to Azure deployed web app using while using CNAME redirect

Tags: dns, azure, cname

I am running into an issue with logging into an ASP.NET MVC web site using Forms Authentication while running on Azure using a CNAME to redirect my domain to the url of the Azure application.  For clarity on how I am setup the following blog post explains how I am setup. http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure

The problem:
When I enter my credentials and click submit on the login form, the login in the code successfully executes and redirects to the Home page however, it appears that the browser does not think it is logged in.  I can tell this because a logged in user will only have the option to log out, but I am seeing the login link.  So maybe it is my code right?  Well maybe, and I hope it is but what I have noticed is that the problem only occurs if I am trying to login from my domain "www.MyDomain.com".  If I use the Azure url mydomain.cloudapp.net, then the login in works fine.  The other interesting part is if I login from mydomain.cloudapp.net and then navigate to www.MyDomain.com I see that I am logged in and everything works properly.

Please help.

Thank you very much,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to pinpoint your exact problem here. You can have a look at [Lokad.Translate](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-translate/): it's a simple open source ASP.NET MVC app designed for Azure. It works with Forms authentication, and our implementation appears to be running fine with the CNAME redirects. You could try to reproduce our setup for your own needs.

Comment: Hello Joannes, where are you handling the CNAME redirects?

Comment: CNAME redirects is done in through the DNS manager (we use a 3rd party DNS provider). Within the app it self, CNAME has zero impact on client code - not a single line actually.

Comment: Hey Joannes, sorry for taking so long to award the answer.  I actually don't remember now how I solved it.  Bad Me.  Thanks for Answering!